# How to improve FPS on Minecraft servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When playing singleplayer I get upwards of 100 FPS and I have a very capable computer, however on multiplayer servers I get less than 50 FPS. I have quite a slow internet connection however I wasn't aware that WiFi speed could affect framerate. I also have tried using multiple different clients to try and improve performance; I am currently using Lunar client which has helped but not to the same level of performance as in singleplayer.

Is there anything else that I could try?

Comment: It's because the game has to render other players as well as the world, I suspect. The FPS drop is therotically normal.

Comment: Well, thats kinda disappointing. I regularly play Skyblock on Hypixel and get ~20 FPS in the large hubs but I see other people (mainly YouTubers) who get 100+ FPS. I was just wondering whether its an Internet issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your framerate is not affected by your internet connection. The things that do affect the framerate are in-game things that are the same on servers as in singleplayer.

Servers just tend to have more stuff that lowers your framerate. Lobbies often have a lot of terrain to be generated, lots of players and other entities and tons of particles everywhere, which all lower your framerate.

Of course, you can improve the framerate by going to the video settings and lowering render distance, disable particles, etc. Another way of boosting your computer's performance is by installing modifications to the game, the most popular one being OptiFine.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi does nothing about the framerate. So don't touch it.

The problem is in game settings.
version 1.8-1.8.9 you can try the following:
Go to settings, Video settings

And do this

Max Framerate: Unlimited

Particles: Minimal

Clouds: Off

Use VSync: Off

Smooth Lighting: Off

And if you play on HyPixel, you can disable players in the lobby.